# knockout binding not work for second time

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I use knockout in MVC c# project. I have shopping cart button on my web page and use below code to load shopping cart as modal dialog.
This code works for first time but when I click again on shopping card it's not work. I know this problem is related to **ko.applyBindings(new CartViewModel());** but I don't how to resolve it,

Any solutions and ideas are welcome.

```
 $("#ShoppingCartButton").on("click", function () {
      $("#ShoppingCartDialog").load("/Order/ShoppingCart", function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new CartViewModel());
            $("#ShoppingCartDialog").modal('show');
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should apply binding only for #ShoppingCartDialog,

```
ko.applyBindings(new CartViewModel(), "ShoppingCartDialog");
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could try to do is remove the binding first, and then apply the binding again. You probably also want to bind the viewmodel to just the `shoppingCartDialog`:

```
$("#ShoppingCartButton").on("click", function () {
    //remove the binding
    ko.cleanNode($("#ShoppingCartDialog")[0]);

    $("#ShoppingCartDialog").load("/Order/ShoppingCart", function () {

        //bind a new viewModel, just to the shoppingcartdialog.
        ko.applyBindings(new CartViewModel(),$("#ShoppingCartDialog")[0]);

        $("#ShoppingCartDialog").modal('show');
    });
});
```